# Why won't my file rename itself?

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on an android app and I want to rename a file. The problem is that it is not renaming:

```
 File f = adapter.getItem(i);
 File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), "helloworld");
 if (f.renameTo(file)) {
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

**Solution BIg Thanks to @S.D.(see comments)**

```
File f = adapter.getItem(i);
     File file = new File(f.getParent(), "helloworld");
     if (f.renameTo(file)) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Comment: What is the nature of the problem? Does it throw an exception, or just return false?

Comment: Replace `f.getAbsolutePath()`  with `f.getParent()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that:

```
File f = adapter.getItem(i);
```

Gives use some `File f`, say where `f` cooresponds to say: `user2351234/Desktop`.  Then, you do:

```
 File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), "helloworld");
```

Which says to make a `File file`, where `file` cooresponds to: `user2351234/Desktop/helloworld`.  Next, you call:

```
f.renameTo(file)
```

which attempts to rename `f`, `user2351234/Desktop` to `user2351234/Desktop/helloworld`, which doesn't make sense since in order for `user2351234/Desktop/helloworld` to exist, `user2351234/Desktop` would have to exist, but by virtue of the operation it would no longer exist.

My hypothesis **may not** be the reason why, but from [Why doesn't File.renameTo(…) create sub-directories of destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817142/why-doesnt-file-renameto-create-sub-directories-of-destination?rq=1), apparently `renameTo` **will** return `false` if the sub-directory does not exist.

**If you want to just change the name of the file, do this:**

```
File f = adapter.getItem(i);
String file = f.getAbsolutePath() + "helloworld";
f = new File(file);
```

**EDIT:**
My proposed solution should work, but if my hypothesis about why your way does not work is incorrect, you may want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows/1006489#1006489) from [Reliable File.renameTo() alternative on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Do you see an exception or does it return false?

Question 2: Did you give permission for the app to write to the SD card? (I'm assuming that's where this file lies). 
The permission to add is"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This posting: [How to rename a file on sdcard with Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application) seems to answer a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/nameoffile.ext" ;
File from = new File(sdcard,"originalname.ext");
File to = new File(sdcard,"newname.ext");
from.renameTo(to);
```